# Query Security Events in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer, query

I enabled Object Access auditing on my Windows 10 laptop using the instructions on [this page](https://www.lepide.com/how-to/track-changes-made-to-your-files-and-folders.html).  I then enabled auditing on a file (i.e. Sleep Times.csv).  I accessed the file and manually looked through the Windows Logs > Security events in Event Viewer.  I found that an event was generated.

I would like to execute a query that shows me all of the events where Object Name == ...\Sleep Times.csv.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following using command prompt as an administrator:

```
wevtutil qe Security | findstr /C:"Sleep Times"
```

Comment: I think `/C:` is causing the error message `FIND: Invalid switch`

Comment: @Nathan Need to use `findstr` not `find`.